# Нубский вопрос по тредам и коллбекам

Tags: callback, java, многопоточность

Мне нужно создать некий тред. Этот тред должен следить за определенной переменной, и в случае если она поменяет свое значение что-то делать. Я так понимаю, человечество на этот случай придумало callback'и.

Можете кинуть в меня примерами/ссылками как реализовать подобное? Я в Java новичок, даже не представляю что гуглить.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это неправильный подход — следить за переменной (поллингом, я правильно понял?) Тот, за кем вы следите, должен оповещать потенциальных интересующихся об изменениях _сам_. Гуглите паттерн «observer».

Comment: @VladD Я реализую загрузочный экран. По моей задумке, функция load() должна по своему завершению установить переменную loaded в положение true, сработает коллбэк, и загрузочный экран сменится на меню. Вы считаете, это неправильный подход?

Comment: @VladD разве то, что я хочу реализовать не есть типичный observer?

Comment: @MyNameIsWinner: Нет, это не правильно. Объект сам лучше знает, как и когда оповестить других об изменениях.

---
Насколько я вас понял, вы хотите не observer, а поллинг. Для observer'а не нужен дополнительный поток.

Comment: @VladD Да, но ведь вы сами предложили мне паттерн observer. Даже следуя из названия (наблюдатель), это тоже самое, что я предложил я. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @MyNameIsWinner: А что есть по-вашему паттерн «observer»?

Comment: @MyNameIsWinner

- Как можно делать вывод о паттерне, исходя из его названия? :) В [паттерне Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) есть объект-наблюдатель и есть субъект его наблюдения. При этом \*субъект\* нотифицирует всех своих наблюдателей о своих изменениях, а не наблюдатель опрашивает субъект (то есть работа осуществляется по принципу push, а не poll).

- Проецируя этот паттерн на ваш пример, изменение переменной должно приводить к нотификации всех подписчиков: "привет, я изменилась, мое новое значение такое-то".

Comment: @VladD Почитал определение на Википедии. Да, я неправильно представлял себе наблюдателя. Хорошо, а как мне тогда лучше всего посылать сигнал наблюдателю, что функция load() выполнена?

Comment: @MyNameIsWinner: ну, в википедии (английской, и даже русской) есть пример кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запретите менять наблюдаемую переменную напрямую, а только лишь через специальный метод. В этом же методе оповещайте ваш ждущий тред. Способов оповещения много, самый простой и надежный - через блокирующую очережь послать сообщение. Еще проще, если реакция на событие не занимает много времени, сразу же эту реакцию исполнить. Если метод, модифицирующий переменную, не знает, какова должна быть реакция, то передайте эту реакцию в объект модифицирующего метода по ссылке. Ссылка может быть на тот Runnable, который сейчас вы передаете треду.